# How to automatically set the random seed on current time?

Tags: r, random, random-seed

Every time one opens a R console, the random seed is set to the same value. On my computer (it might be the same on your machine), if I run `rnorm(1)`, I always get `0.1777571` at the first call.

I tried to automatically set the random seed using the computer current time by adding something like

```
set.seed(
   as.integer(
      as.numeric(
         gsub("[^0-9]","",paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y %X %x")))
      )%%.Machine$integer.max
   )
)
```

in the file `.Rprofile` but it does not change anything. The first call to `rnorm(1)` always return `0.1777571`.

How can I automatically set the random seed to the computer current time?

**EDIT**

I open R session directly on the terminal. I just hit `r` and do not explicitly load any previous workspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for `set.seed` says a couple of interesting things:

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current
>   time and the process ID when one is required. Hence different sessions
>   will give different simulation results, by default. However, the seed
>   might be restored from a previous session if a previously saved
>   workspace is restored.

The behavior that you describe is consistent with a previous version of `.Random.seed` being restored when a previous workspace is loaded, which seems like it must be *after* the code that you have in `.RProfile` is run.

Another interesting thing is that the documentation suggests that simply using `set.seed(NULL)` will do the sort of thing you want with less work.

Here is a thread from an R mailing list which discusses this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-October/255734.html

Comment: mmhhh... Well I don't explicitly load any workspace. I just hit `r` in bash to open a new session in a terminal window.

Comment: @Remi.b You don't need to explicitly load a previously saved workspace, it will load as part of the startup process. See the link that I added on edit. If the workspace that you are loading has no visible objects then it is possible to not even notice it -- except that it is restoring the hidden `.Random.seed`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. Now that you say so I see that it writes `[Previously saved workspace restored]` when I open R. I deleted the file `/Users/remi/.RData` and the problem was solved!

Comment: nicely diagnosed