# R: sample function repeats same results

Tags: r, random, sample, mersenne-twister

I ran into something very weird with `sample()`. If I run the following line 5 times at the start of a session (in either RStudio or R), I would get the following results.

```
sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "b" "y" "d" "p" "n"
[1] "v" "n" "i" "s" "s"
[1] "d" "q" "a" "m" "x"
[1] "w" "s" "u" "h" "e"
[1] "b" "y" "g" "s" "e"
```

But if I restart the console and run it 5 times at the beginning of a new session, I would somehow get the same results -- every time. Is `sample()` (which I believe uses Mersenne Twister by default) supposed to do this? What should I do instead to get results that don't actually repeat?

Comment: Are you saving and loading your workspace at the beginning of each R session? Or do you have a `set.seed()` call in your `.Rprofile` file for some reason?

Comment: I don't save my workspace, and I have never intentionally used any `set.seed()` call. (And I don't think I did it by accident either since I rarely use R, and yet it has the same problem as RStudio, which is what I work with exclusively.)

Comment: Use `rm(.Random.seed)` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982672/how-to-automatically-set-the-random-seed-on-current-time. It's still possible a workspace loading is causing this, I think if you have ever saved your workspace, it will be loaded automatically whenever R loads. Check your home directory for a file named `.Rdata` and delete it (as long as you're sure you don't need it)

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(123)
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "h" "u" "k" "w" "y"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "b" "n" "x" "o" "l"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "y" "l" "r" "o" "c"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "x" "g" "b" "i" "y"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "x" "s" "q" "z" "r"
```

If you start a new session and change the `set.seed` value, you will get different results.

```
> set.seed(456)

> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "c" "f" "t" "w" "u"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "i" "c" "h" "g" "k"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "j" "f" "t" "v" "p"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "q" "v" "l" "s" "h"
> sample(letters,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] "e" "s" "x" "l" "v"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, though I see any given seed will still produce the same results at each turn. Juan's solution of running `rm(.Random.seed)` seems to work for me as the results never repeat.

Comment: @dasf it's not clear to me what you mean by 'same result'. By setting a seed, you would expect to get the same result for that seed.

Comment: I mean I would get `bydpn` if I run the code at beginning of a session, `vniss` if I run that code again, `dqamx` if again, ... and if I quit and restart the console and repeat the same process, I would get `bydpn`, `vniss`, `dqamx`... . I've never dealt with seed setting before and wasn't aware of this problem until now.